# Writing text and a variable into HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables

here is my code. I would like to print the variable 'fName' and the text prior into the div (with the ID 'feedback').

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var first = document.getElementById("fName").value;
        var last = document.getElementById("lName").value;

        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML += "Hello" + fName;
    }
    </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: okay? what's the problem?

Comment: `fName` (variable) is not defined in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the variables you have defined:

```
<script> 
function myFunction() { 
  var first = document.getElementById("fName").value; 
  var last = document.getElementById("lName").value;

  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML += "Hello " + first + " " + last; 
} 
</script>
```